# How to load images from the local machine to JS object avoiding loading to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load an image file from the computer directly to any js object without using any server-side component. For example, I want to select a picture from the local machine and display it on a webpage. Is there a way to avoid file upload to the server?

In fact I want to write a kind of multiple image loader, but before loading to the server I want to rotate some images, create an xml-file with some data like user id, image file names list and to zip all images and this xml and then send it to the server. How can I do that on the client side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load local image into browser using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996004/load-local-image-into-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: Indeed - it seems this is not possible...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a way with HTML5, but it requires the user to have dropped the file into a drop target or used a `<input type="file"/>` box, since otherwise it would be a security issue.

Using the `File` API you can read files, and specifically you can use the `FileReader.readAsDataURL` method to set the content as a `data:` URL for the image tag.

Here's an example:

```
$('#f').on('change', function(ev) {
    var f = ev.target.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function(ev2) {
        console.dir(ev2);
        $('#i').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(f);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Qszjg/

Comment: How is cross-origin rules related?

Comment: @Christian because they restrict access to `file:///` if you've loaded a page from `http:///`.

Comment: I don't see how it relates since he's not trying to access a different page or something like that. While cross-origin policy in terms of accessing a server exists, you can always throw stuff into a form and post dynamically.

Comment: @Christian that's the point I was trying to make about user interaction.  You can get the user to put stuff in a form, and with HTML5 `File` have the browser work on it.  AFAIK you can't just launch code to read file without the user having chosen the files themselves.

Comment: That would be unrelated to cross-origin policy, it's something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [new File APIs](http://caniuse.com/#search=fileapi), it is possible to access content from the local disk.

You put a traditional `<input type="file">` upload field on your page, and handle the `onchange` event.

[MDN has a good writeup with all of the details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Your event handler gets a `FileList` containing `Files`.  From there, you can call [`FileReader.readAsDataURL(File)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) to fetch the content of the image and then pass that data URL to an `<img>` or a `<canvas>` to do rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) method of the window.URL object, this doesn't have much browser support though

http://jsfiddle.net/LvAqp/ only works in chrome and firefox