# Uploading a PNG into a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

After a few hours of research, I have not found the best way of uploading a PNG so it can be used inside a Canvas element. All the solutions that I have found use server side code one way or another. I want this solution to be entirely client side. Is there a way to do this?

Workflow:

User uploads an image

JS gets access to this image in some form (base64)

Image gets loaded into a Canvas

Comment: Something [like this (file drop)](http://abdiassoftware.com/easycanvas/samples/sample_dropimages.html) ?

Comment: Not quite, but almost! I want the user to be able to select the image from a system file finder prompt. Notice how they say that everything is done locally in the browser. I'll take a look at their code to see how they accomplish the file upload.

Comment: Or something like so? http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: Or duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603644/how-to-load-images-from-the-local-machine-to-js-object-avoiding-loading-to-the-s

Comment: @GuySirton that's an img, AlexanderVentura wants Canvas. Still a good starting point.

Comment: Definitely a good starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as what i have understood and you asked for a complete client-side solution i think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvk9p/1/

```
<script>

function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
var c=document.getElementById("imgPreview");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("uploadPreview");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
    };
};

</script>
```

Comment: My only issue with this solution is the browser compatability of FileReader.

Comment: @AlexanderVentura I tested it Mozilla , Chrome and Opera and its working correctly.

Comment: Does not work on <= IE 9. I think for this particular use case this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

It is possible to read the files that are being passed in an `input` of `type="file"` from JavaScript, <strike>the problem is reading the file as an image and placing it in the canvas</strike> this can be worked by loading the image in a `img` element and then draw the image from the img element into the `canvas` as [shown by Zword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20796117/402022).

---

*My original answer*

You can take advantage of the project [`JavaScript-Load-Image`](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) by Sebastian Tschan (aka blueimp). See the [demo](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/).

It has been very easy to set up a working example based on it:

```
<script src="load-image.min.js"></script>
<input id="file-input" type="file">
<script>
    document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = function (e)
    {
        var loadingImage = loadImage(
            e.target.files[0],
            function (img)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            },
            {maxWidth: 600}
        );
        if (!loadingImage)
        {
            // Alternative code ...
        }
    };
</script>
```

*Note*: The above code uses [load-image.min.js](https://raw.github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/master/js/load-image.min.js), download it for use. I don't provide a "jsfiddle" (or similar) because I haven't found this lib on any CDN.