# How to display a pdf in a web page from a network share

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I wish to display a pdf from a local share when a user clicks on a row. I have a page that gets built by php that retrieves file paths from a database and adds them to a "onclick" event in a table row. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603644/how-to-load-images-from-the-local-machine-to-js-object-avoiding-loading-to-the-s) question that explains how to display an image from a path. I changed the img tag to this

```
<embed id='i' width="500" height="375">
```

and it works with a pdf.  I can not get it to work with a path.  Is this impossible?  It would be nice to display the image in a page but if I can not then can I launch the reader?

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vg8x90rt/).

Alternately if I can force the file selection dialog to display the path and make the user click "ok" would be acceptable.  A little kludgy, but acceptable.

Comment: You can try to use PDF.js https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Any examples on using that library?  I can not find any and I suspect I can easily end up with the same issue since PDF.js "renders pfds" and I have no issue rendering pdfs.  The problem is converting a path to a file object (at least in the method I am using).

Answer (score -2):

Do you can to put the pdf in a object tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp,do you can do this in php in this way

```
      $selelect = mysql_query("Your select...");   
    while($row = mysql_feech_array($selelect)){

        echo '<object data="'.$row['way..'].'" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"> 
alt : <a href="Name">Name.pdf</a> </object>';   
    }
```

Comment: The problem with that is no php code needs to be run at the point the image is to be displayed.  All the information is already on the local machine.