# Reducing the size of image file for faster uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a simple code to upload files using ajax to server, but i don't know how i can resize the image before that process to improve the performance ..

Code of Previewing image.

```
function Preview_Image(index){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(filesList[index]);
    $('#loaded-image-frame' + index + ' #preview').html(img);
    img.onload = function () {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    }
}
```

Code of Uploading image..

```
function Upload_ResizedImage(index){
    var image = filesList[index]
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file[]', image);
    process = $.ajax({
       url: "ControlPanelAjax.ashx?job=UploadImages,
       type: "POST",
       data: form_data,
       processData: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       beforeSend: function (event) { },
       success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
           if (data != '-1') {
              alert("image uploaded correctly");
           }
           else {
              alert("Error Uploading..");
           }
       },
       complete: function (event) {},
       error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
       xhr: function () {}
   });
}
```

**Note: filesList is an array containing files that i made up**

Comment: You  can't resize until it's uploaded

Comment: try to use image intervention library you can resize image before uploading to server

Comment: I think that javascript has the some tools helping to do that

Comment: @nogad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603644/how-to-load-images-from-the-local-machine-to-js-object-avoiding-loading-to-the-s

Comment: brother nogad, i know how previewing the image as your link show, but i want to upload image after resizing it to make that faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using canvas from HTML5. Here is [a tutorial](http://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop) and here is the related code

HTML:

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('filesToUpload').onchange = function(){
        var files = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
        }
    };
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function resizeAndUpload(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {

    var tempImg = new Image();
    tempImg.src = reader.result;
    tempImg.onload = function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
        var tempW = tempImg.width;
        var tempH = tempImg.height;
        if (tempW > tempH) {
            if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
               tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
               tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
               tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
               tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = tempW;
        canvas.height = tempH;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
            document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
        };

        xhr.open('POST', 'uploadResized.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
        xhr.send(data);
      }

   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST) {
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tasos for your answer, because i have nothing experience in PHP so i have questions .. what does this code do? :   $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img); and what about $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

Comment: It just takes a jpeg base64 string and remove the data image from it. To have the clear content only. If you want more file types, you need to check if it is jpeg, png or other and use `data:image/png;base64` instead.