# Difference between Ajax file load and <input> file load?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have some javascript that processes and validates some custom XML.  Currently the reference to the file is hard coded using Ajax:

```
$.get("test.xml", {}, XmlOnLoad );
```

When I debug the value passed to XmlOnLoad is a `#document` with a `conentType` of `application/xml`

I need to be able to load different files.  I found [the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568359/display-an-image-on-the-page-without-uploading-to-server) and tried to adapt it but I'm having an issue.  When it passes to the XmlOnLoad it is a `file` with a `type` of `text/xml`.  As a result, it fails when I use any XML functions like `childNodes()`.  Here is the code as I have it now:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        XmlOnLoad(input.files[0])
    }
}
```

What can I do differently to get it to process successfully as an XML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the file to a blob url and use $.get.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        $.get(URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]), {}, XmlOnLoad, 'xml' );
    }
}
```